# Chart.JS spacing and padding

Tags: chart.js

1. Is it possible to get some more space between the chart and the x-axis?
2. Is it possible to get some more space between the right side of the chart and the end of the canvas area? I want to add some more elements to the canvas right beside the chart but this is not possible because the chart takes the whole canvas width so it would overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Shifting x axis Labels Vertically**

The easiest way to do 1. is by adding spaces to your x labels. You can extend your chart type and override your initialize function to do this (increase 30 to something larger if your labels are long to start with anyway)

```
initialize: function(data){
    data.labels.forEach(function(item, index) {
        data.labels[index] += Array(Math.max(30 - item.length, 0)).join(" ");
    })
    Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

*Edit* : As pointed out in the comments, this causes a horizontal shift as well and the label ends no longer align with the x axis markers.

Since both the x axis and the x labels are drawn in a single function and you have no other variables you can mess around with (safely) this means you'll have to change the actual scale draw function.

Look for a ctx.translate towards the end of the draw function and change it to

```
ctx.translate(xPos, (isRotated) ? this.endPoint + 22 : this.endPoint + 18);
```

You'll also have to adjust the endpoint (which drives the y limits) a bit so that the additional y offset doesn't cause the labels to overflow the chart (look for the line adjusting this in the draw override for 2.).

**Leaving a gap on the Right Side**

To do 2, you override your draw function (in your extended chart) and change xScalePaddingRight. However since this doesn't affect your horizontal grid lines you have to overlay a filled rectangle once your draw is complete. Your complete draw function would look like this

```
draw: function(){
    // this line is for 1.
    if (!this.scale.done) {
         this.scale.endPoint -= 20
         // we should do this only once
         this.scale.done = true;
    }
    var xScalePaddingRight = 120
    this.scale.xScalePaddingRight = xScalePaddingRight
    Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
    this.chart.ctx.fillStyle="#FFF";
    this.chart.ctx.fillRect(this.chart.canvas.width - xScalePaddingRight, 0, xScalePaddingRight, this.chart.canvas.height);
}
```

Original fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gvdmxc5t/

Fiddle with modified Scale draw function - https://jsfiddle.net/xgc6a77a/ (I turned off animation in this one so that the endpoint is shifted only once, but you could just hard code it, or add some extra code so that it's done only once)

Comment: 2. Is working fine, thank you :) The problem with 1. is that the labels also move horizontal and they are not aligned to the points above. You can see this in your jsfiddle, too. And second they also are rotated though there is enough space for them to be not rotated (can we disable rotation?).

Comment: Ah ok, good point. That makes it a bit more complex - I have updated the answer. Btw, we can disable rotation by putting in a this.scale.xLabelRotation too before the prototype draw (but the labels overlap for my data). Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vq9my5zc/

Comment: To add vertical padding to the X axis without modifying the library itself, you can change `scale.height` for bottom padding and set `tickMarkLength` to 15px, for example, then clear out a 5px portion of tick lines with `clearRect` in `afterDraw` callback.

Answer (score 5):

**The 'tickMarkLength'** option extends the grid lines outside the chart and pushes the ticks down.

```
xAxes: [
        {
            gridLines: {
              tickMarkLength: 15  
            },
        }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

use this for *chartjs 2.0*

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        categoryPercentage: 0.55
}]
```

[Reference](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage)

Answer (score 0):

In chartjs v3, there is an "offset" flag that you can set to true. This will create padding.

```
scales: {
  x: {
     offset: true,
  }
}
```

> If true, extra space is added to the both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area. This is set to true for a bar chart by default.

[Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes)