# How to add padding between Graph and X/Y-Scale in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have a simple Line-Chart using `chart.js`.

It should look something like this: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150819/ktkgs9pw.jpg (Photoshop, I marked the paddings with red lines)

What it looks like at the moment with `chart.js`: http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150819/ql5l3jez.png

As you can see, the outline of the Graph-Points overlaps the X-Scale at the bottom, which is "2:00 PM" for example and the Y-Scale on the left, which is "0" for example.

My Line-Chart-Code:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="server-usage"></canvas>
```

**Global Chartsettings:**

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
            // Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
            animation: false,

            // Number - Number of animation steps
            animationSteps: 60,

            // String - Animation easing effect
            // Possible effects are:
            // [easeInOutQuart, linear, easeOutBounce, easeInBack, easeInOutQuad,
            //  easeOutQuart, easeOutQuad, easeInOutBounce, easeOutSine, easeInOutCubic,
            //  easeInExpo, easeInOutBack, easeInCirc, easeInOutElastic, easeOutBack,
            //  easeInQuad, easeInOutExpo, easeInQuart, easeOutQuint, easeInOutCirc,
            //  easeInSine, easeOutExpo, easeOutCirc, easeOutCubic, easeInQuint,
            //  easeInElastic, easeInOutSine, easeInOutQuint, easeInBounce,
            //  easeOutElastic, easeInCubic]
            animationEasing: "easeInOutQuart",

            // Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
            showScale: true,

            // Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
            scaleOverride: true,

            // ** Required if scaleOverride is true **
            // Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
            scaleSteps: 7,
            // Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
            scaleStepWidth: 18,
            // Number - The scale starting value
            scaleStartValue: 0,

            // String - Colour of the scale line
            scaleLineColor: "#565a60",

            // Number - Pixel width of the scale line
            scaleLineWidth: 0.1,

            // Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale
            scaleShowLabels: true,

            // Interpolated JS string - can access value
            scaleLabel: "<%=value%>",

            // Boolean - Whether the scale should stick to integers, not floats even if drawing space is there
            scaleIntegersOnly: true,

            // Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
            scaleBeginAtZero: false,

            // String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
            scaleFontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",

            // Number - Scale label font size in pixels
            scaleFontSize: 13,

            // String - Scale label font weight style
            scaleFontStyle: "500",

            // String - Scale label font colour
            scaleFontColor: "#7c8189",

            // Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
            responsive: true,

            // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
            maintainAspectRatio: false,

            // Boolean - Determines whether to draw tooltips on the canvas or not
            showTooltips: true,

            // Function - Determines whether to execute the customTooltips function instead of drawing the built in tooltips (See [Advanced - External Tooltips](#advanced-usage-custom-tooltips))
            customTooltips: false,

            // Array - Array of string names to attach tooltip events
            tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"],

            // String - Tooltip background colour
            tooltipFillColor: "#42454a",

            // String - Tooltip label font declaration for the scale label
            tooltipFontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",

            // Number - Tooltip label font size in pixels
            tooltipFontSize: 15,

            // String - Tooltip font weight style
            tooltipFontStyle: "normal",

            // String - Tooltip label font colour
            tooltipFontColor: "#e7e7e7",

            // String - Tooltip title font declaration for the scale label
            tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",

            // Number - Tooltip title font size in pixels
            tooltipTitleFontSize: 14,

            // String - Tooltip title font weight style
            tooltipTitleFontStyle: "regular",

            // String - Tooltip title font colour
            tooltipTitleFontColor: "#fff",

            // Number - pixel width of padding around tooltip text
            tooltipYPadding: 6,

            // Number - pixel width of padding around tooltip text
            tooltipXPadding: 6,

            // Number - Size of the caret on the tooltip
            tooltipCaretSize: 8,

            // Number - Pixel radius of the tooltip border
            tooltipCornerRadius: 0,

            // Number - Pixel offset from point x to tooltip edge
            tooltipXOffset: 10,

            // String - Template string for single tooltips
            tooltipTemplate: "On <%if (label){%><%=label%> there were <%}%><%= value %> active users",

            // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

            // Function - Will fire on animation progression.
            onAnimationProgress: function(){},

            // Function - Will fire on animation completion.
            onAnimationComplete: function(){}
}
```

**Some Chart-Data:**

```
var usageData = {
     labels : ["2:00 PM","4:00 PM","6:00 PM","8:00 PM","10:00 PM","0:00 AM","2:00 AM"],
     datasets : [
         {
               strokeColor : "#61666c",
               pointColor : "#4e82c9",
               pointStrokeColor : "#565a60",
               data : [0,120,120,100,60,40,0]
          }
     ]
}
```

**Chart-Options:**

```
var options = {

            ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
            scaleShowGridLines : false,

            //String - Colour of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

            //Number - Width of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

            //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
            scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,

            //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
            scaleShowVerticalLines: true,

            //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
            bezierCurve : false,

            //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
            bezierCurveTension : 0.4,

            //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
            pointDot : true,

            //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
            pointDotRadius : 18,

            //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 8,

            //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
            pointHitDetectionRadius : 20,

            //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
            datasetStroke : true,

            //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
            datasetStrokeWidth : 4,

            //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a colour
            datasetFill : false,

            //String - A legend template
            legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

};
```

**Creating the Chart:**

```
var serverUsage = document.getElementById('server-usage').getContext('2d');
new Chart(serverUsage).Line(usageData, options);
```

I found a pretty similar question after searching for the Question-Tag chart.js, but it didn't work too good, since the solution is buggy when hovering and it's not a Line-Chart. ([Chart.JS spacing and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697292/chart-js-spacing-and-padding))

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I've fixed it in the linked answer's fiddle.

Comment: @potatopeelings Thanks for updating your great solution! Could you create the solution for Line-Graphs aswell or explain how to do it on my own? My JavaScript skills really are like 0 - so I just live from those libraries and people like you, who help adjusting them. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I have made a few assumptions looking at your current code. Let me know if those aren't correct. By the way, you needn't set your `Chart.defaults.global` like in your question. You can just override the ones you have to like `Chart.defaults.global.scaleSteps = 7; Chart.defaults.global.animation = false;` And for your individual chart options you just need to include the options you want to override in your options object - you can leave the rest out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need all the complexity from the linked solution because

1. You intend to not show the axes lines (I see from the image that you will set the chart background and the scale color to be the same) and
2. You've already hardcoded the scale start and end values (by which I assume you know the range of values your data will be in and don't need it autocalculated) - see the alternative solution if this condition doesn't hold for you

---

With those caveats, you just need to make a few changes (just Ctrl + F on the option name to find the line to replace)

```
scaleSteps: 5,
// Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
scaleStepWidth: 50,
// Number - The scale starting value
scaleStartValue: -50,
```

We're basically starting the scale to start from a value 1 step lower than what we need. This lifts up the graph. Now all we need to do is hide this extra scale label, which we do with

```
scaleLabel: function (d) {
    if (d.value < 0)
        return '';
    else
        return d.value + '         ';
},
```

The first line in the method takes care of hiding the extra scale label. The `+ '       '` on the last line moves the graph to the right (we tell Chart.js that the labels are longer than they really are)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/56578cn4/

---

[image]

---

If 2. doesn't apply, remove the scaleOverride and configuration and override the common method that calculates the y axis scale range before you initialize the chart to add one scale label above and one below

```
// this applies to all chart instances that use this scale!
var originalCalculateScaleRange = Chart.helpers.calculateScaleRange;
Chart.helpers.calculateScaleRange = function () {
    var scaleRange = originalCalculateScaleRange.apply(this, arguments);
    // add 1 unit at the top and bottom
    scaleRange.min = scaleRange.min - scaleRange.stepValue;
    scaleRange.max = scaleRange.max + scaleRange.stepValue;
    scaleRange.steps = scaleRange.steps + 2;
    return scaleRange;
}
```

This will work fine assuming you don't mind the extra labels when the values are all above 0 (our scaleLabel option takes care of hiding negative labels, and negative labels only).

Note that if you are using other charts where you don't want this to apply you'll need to revert this after you are done initializing your chart.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mkzdzj3b/

Comment: First of all: Thank you very much!
Edit: It always autosends the answer when pressing enter damn.

So: I don't really know the range of values my data will be in. Why I hardcoded it for now: Otherwise, the scala will be on the next 100-step, which I don't want to. I want to calculate a good Start/StepWidth and total number of Step-Value in PHP actually. That means your answer works itself, but not with other datasets, because the padding will vary at the end.

I hope you got my point.
But thanks for your time so far!

Comment: Thanks again for your edit!
The Paddings seem to work fine, but without my Scala Values, I got an unnecessary big y-Scala.

Picture: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150819/no5gv92l.png
Is it possible to make the highest Value in the Graph equal to the highest point on the Y-Scala? Or maybe a gap which is not as big as it is at the moment.

Anyway thanks for your time again!

Comment: Try messing around with the calculateScaleRange function to reduce scaleRange.max value till it's within 1 stepValue of your data's max (you need to reduce scaleRange.steps to match up btw) - see the modified function here http://jsfiddle.net/pLn56oL6/

Comment: I don't really get how to adjust it the way I want, but that fiddle seems to be good enough though.
I can just thank you very much and wish you a great day for all your help!

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. We allow chart.js to do it's scale calculation. Then we adjust the top of the scale to be within 2 steps of your maximum data value. What change were you looking to do? Bte if it's too close to the edge you circle get clipped.

Comment: Yea I just noticed that, my Circles are very big, compared to other Graphs. I think the current solution should work like a charm actually. Again, it might be too much now, but that's all I can do in return: Thank you. Keep up the good work!