# Chart.js add padding to scales

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need to add padding on the x and y axis. This question ([How to add padding between Graph and X/Y-Scale in chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095839/how-to-add-padding-between-graph-and-x-y-scale-in-chart-js)) is my exact situation, only I am using Chart.js 2.

See screeshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wndPx.png

Basically my points are large images, so they are running off the chart. Is there a way to add padding to the chart area or scales so they fit better?

Comment: do you have any code in place showing your current result?

Answer (score 60):

Figured out a way to do it with the yAxes:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                padding: 100
            }
        }], 
    }
}
```

No solution so far on the x axis.
A workaround to your problem though could be to set a lower min by calculating the min of the data and adding subtracting a increment value:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        min: -100
    }
}],
```

Both togheter would be something like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/u9b0nmp8/1/

**Update #1**: X-axis suggestion

**Update #2**: improved alternative to the x-Axis based on 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38620312/6638478

**Update #3**: version 2.7 and up now supports padding on both y and x axis. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/u9b0nmp8/207/

Comment: This solution didn't work for me but this one did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38620312/259881

Comment: Thats a good idea for the x axis, wouldn't create padding, but it would create some space, which solves the problem.