# Chart.js: How can I set paddings and draw a background box in a line chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKbsO.png) is a graph what I want to draw using Chart.js.

The label begins with 2019 and end with 2021, but there should be paddings.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't works.

```
options: {
  layout: {
     padding: 20
  }
}
```

Additionally I want to draw a horizontal box using Annotation, but I couldn't draw it.

```
annotation: {
    annotations: [
        {
            drawTime: "beforeDatasetsDraw",
            type: "box",
            xScaleID: "x-axis-1",
            yScaleID: "y-axis-1",
            xMin: 0,
            xMax: 100,
            yMin: 0,
            yMax: 200,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.8)",
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    ]
},
```

How can I draw the graph?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js add padding to scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985154/chart-js-add-padding-to-scales)

Comment: The default X en y scale IDs are x and y, that should make your annotation appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the padding the easyest thing you can do is to just add 2 `null` values, 1 in front of the labels array and one as final element to create space. For the box annotation as I mentioned in a comment your scale ID's are wrong

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [null, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, null],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 2019,
        y: 100
      }, {
        x: 2021,
        y: 400
      }, {
        x: 2022,
        y: 100
      }],
      borderColor: 'pink',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      radius: 5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [{
          drawTime: "beforeDatasetsDraw",
          type: "box",
          xScaleID: "x",
          yScaleID: "y",
          xMin: 0,
          xMax: 100,
          yMin: 0,
          yMax: 200,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.8)",
          borderWidth: 0
        }]
      },
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.0.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
</body>
```