# Chart JS line chart right margin (point chopped at the edge)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm trying to add a margin to my chart from the right, so that the final point is not chopped as shown here:
[last point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE8y0.png)

Code demo: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVgwBW)

Solutions I've tried so far:

- Setting the `offset`, which works but it has too much of a margin, to the point where it's not readable on mobilephones
- Setting the `bounds: 'ticks'` option, which works, but when the data is spread among a small timeline, the graph is super crunched up
- The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30700908/11089669) solution seems like the golden answer, however it is not suitable for `v2.7.3`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!